# When does stall take place in this code?

Tags: mips

```
Loop: lw  $t2, 0($t1)
      add $t3, $t2, $s1
      sw  $t3, 4($t1)
      add $t1, $t1, $t9
      bne $t1, $t0, Loop
      and $s2, $s4, $s5
```

I have interpreted that stall takes place in second instruction provided that this loop runs 8 times and we are in third iteration. Can stall take place in any more situation?

Comment: What's `addIt`? Did you mean `add` or `addu`?

Comment: Why do you think that that the stall happens on the second instruction, and under such oddly specific conditions?